# Notification about task execution flask and celery

Tags: python, mongodb, celery

I am using celery and flask with a mongodb backend and broker.
I am trying to understand whats the best way to give a notification after running a group of synchronous task.

Both of the function have a decorator called `@celery.task`

```
def abc():  
    # do something

def fgh():  
    # do something
```

In order to run these programs, I am using `(abc.s() | fgh.s()).delay()` to run these tasks.

How do I signal the main program once these tasks have been executed completely?

Comment: The "best way" depends on the specifics of your application. I've done it in a couple of ways in one application and I'm sure there are quite a few other ways one can do it.

Comment: Could you tell me what's the way how you completed the task

Answer (score 0):

Mb u can try [flask-notification](https://flask-notifications.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) with Redis as Celery backend. Another way: check task state/status (something like `status = celery.AsyncResult(str(task_id)).status`) with waiting intervals `time.sleep(10)` in cycle (for example, `while True: ...`) and update progress bar on some page with jquery. After task completion (SUCCESS or FAILED status) you can show message with `flash('your message')` or set redirect. Hope thats help.